# (Angular) same component with defrent services best practices

Tags: angular

I have a simple autocomplete, and it's work perfectly, the problem is that I need to implement the same code every time with each  database entities (exp: product, store...), I'm looking for the best way to create one component, and dynamically (service side) get my suggested data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: For a autocomplete you can use a @Input as example and you set the data you want to it. So each component load its one data and push it to the autocomplete.

If you wanna one **autocomplete component** and change the service so you say, I think you search for ***Configuring dependency providers***. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) is the official link.

*What does it?*
You can set a service "alias" so to say. You use a service **xy** in your component which loads data for the auto complete, let us say its name is *LoadAutoDataService*. And you wanna change this service on each parent component of the autocomplete component:

```
[{ provide: LoadAutoDataService, useClass: Comp1LoadAutoDataService }]
```

The **Comp1LoadAutoDataService** is a other class which depends on **LoadAutoDataService** but handle it functions other then the original. So every time you use the *LoadAutoDataService* it will replaced with the *Comp1LoadAutoDataService*.

Like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class Comp1LoadAutoDataService extends LoadAutoDataService {
  constructor() { super(); }

  override getData() {
    super.getData(); // Or something else
  }
}
```

***Original***

```
export class LoadAutoDataService {
  constructor() {}

 getData() {
    console.log("Data......");
  }
}
```